# Are there limitations using a PostGIS out-db raster?

Tags: raster, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have been trying to import a large raster into a PostGIS 2.0 database and hit a few stumbling blocks.

Initially when I tried to import the raster using raster2pgsql, I would receive the following error:
**rt_band_set_pixel_line: Coordinates out of range**

After finding [this page](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1839), and using gdalinfo I found that the raster exceeded the maximum allowed size of 65535 x 65535.

gdalinfo output:

> $ gdalinfo ari100.tif
>   Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
>   ... 
>   Size is **42971, 77138**
>   Coordinate System is:
>   GEOGCS["WGS 84",
>   ...
>       AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
>   Origin = (152.741676637167842,-26.215302802012008)
>   Pixel Size = (0.000009239757419,-0.000009239757419)
>   Metadata:
>     AREA_OR_POINT=Area
>   Image Structure Metadata:
>     INTERLEAVE=BAND
>   Corner Coordinates:
>   Upper Left  ( 152.7416766, -26.2153028) (152d44'30.04"E, 26d12'55.09"S)
>   Lower Left  ( 152.7416766, -26.9280392) (152d44'30.04"E, 26d55'40.94"S)
>   Upper Right ( 153.1387183, -26.2153028) (153d 8'19.39"E, 26d12'55.09"S)
>   Lower Right ( 153.1387183, -26.9280392) (153d 8'19.39"E, 26d55'40.94"S)
>   Center      ( 152.9401974, -26.5716710) (152d56'24.71"E, 26d34'18.02"S)
>   Band 1 Block=42971x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
>   ...

So I decided to use the out-db functionality by using the -R flag in raster2pgsql.

From the documentation:
*Register the raster as a filesystem (out-db) raster, Only the metadata of the raster and path location to the raster is stored in the database (not the pixels).*

I imported the raster using the following command:

```
raster2pgsql /gis/Flood/ari100.tif -R | psql -U username database
```

But when I tried a query:

```
SELECT ST_Value(rast, ST_PointFromText('POINT(152.9632 -26.4878)')) FROM ari100
```

I get the following error:

```
NOTICE:  Attempting to get pixel value with out of range raster coordinates: (23975, 29491)  
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "st_value" line 13 at RETURN
```

However, if I use GDAL (through Python) to query the raster directly using [this script](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/samples/val_at_coord.py)

```
python val_at_coord.py 152.9632 -26.4878
```

I can retrieve the value correctly.

I decided to find the extents of the raster in the database:

```
SELECT ST_Height(rast) As rastheight, ST_Width(rast) As rastwidth from ari100;

rastheight | rastwidth  
11602      | 42971
```

The height is completely incorrect (should be 77138).

So my question is: did I do something wrong (in using raster2pgsql) or is there a limitation in using out-db rasters with PostGIS?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note: it looks like it overflowed nicely, since 77138 = 65536+11602.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will definitely want to tile your raster.  The maximum width x
height permitted for the PostGIS raster type is 65535 x 65535,
regardless of whether or not the raster is in-db or out-db.  The other
reason to tile your raster (though this may not apply in your case) is
that the maximum field size permitted by PostgreSQL is 1 GB [1].

As for optimal tile size, I can only suggest two things.

1. Tile sizes <= 100 x 100 are best.  smaller is faster but consumes
   more storage space.
2. If possible, find a tile size that is cleanly divisible from the
   raster's dimensions.  So for a raster of 42971 x 77138, no tile size <=
   100 x 100 works cleanly.  In these situations, I usually just go 50 x 50
   or something in that neighborhood.

-bborie

[1] http://www.postgresql.org/about/