# psql import raster out of memory

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql

I tried to import a dem.tif in a postgres database. I use postgres 9.5. First step was to create file via raster2pgsql. This file dem.sql (800.000kb), I'd like to import via psql into the database. The process start running, create sequence, and primary key, then CREATE TABLE...stop with ERROR out of memory character string with 859735225 Bytes to long for transformation ERROR Transaktion stopped etc. [image]What can I do to bypass this problem?

Comment: post full error

Comment: its in german: 3: out of memory detail character string to long for code transformation 4: Error transaction stopped commands until end of transaction ignored 5: Error transaction stopped commands until end of transaction ignored 6: Error transaction stopped commands until end of transaction ignored

Comment: Try the suggested steps outlined in the PostGIS Raster FAQ section 10.15 http://postgis.net/docs/RT_FAQ.html#qa_raster_fails_encoding_conversion

Comment: I changed database encoding  with: ALTER DATABASE mydb
  SET client_encoding = 'WIN1252'; as suggested in the sql tool in pg admin. was no problem. Import failed afterwards with the same errors...

Comment: @oppia04 what does SHOW server_encoding return?

Comment: UTF8...still !?

Comment: @oppia04 The sever_encoding and the client_encoding are two different settings; you can consider the server_encoding to be what is used inside your database. Set the client_encoding to match this.

Comment: show client encoding return 'unicode'

Comment: o.k. server_encoding is UTF8 so I tried alter database set client_encoding UTF8; query returns succesfully. afterwards show client_encoding returns still unicode? When trying to import error returns changed to invalid memory alloc request size..

Comment: @oppia04 How large is your raster? and did you use the tiling option in your raster2pgsql command? If not, try rerunning your command with the -t widthxheight option and loading the new sql file into your database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65168/discussion-between-oppia04-and-ali).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments/chat, you ran into two errors here. Firstly, the conversion between the client and the server encoding, and secondly, a limitation of raster size.

### Encoding conversion

The encoding conversion issue has been documented in the [PostGIS Raster FAQ](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_FAQ.html#qa_raster_fails_encoding_conversion)

> If your database has set an explicit client encoding different from your database encoding, then when loading large raster files (above 30 MB in size), you may run into a bytes is too long for encoding conversion.

It is important here to note the difference between **server_encoding** and **client_encoding**. Server encoding is what is used within the database and can be viewed using `SHOW server_encoding`; the client encoding setting is the encoding that is used when connecting from a client to the PostgreSQL server e.g., via *psql* in your case. As with the server_encoding, you can query the database for the current client encoding with `SHOW client_encoding`.

To solve this first issue it is recommended to explicitly set the client_encoding to match that of the database (the server_encoding). There are several methods to change the client encoding which you can find in the PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html#AEN39240).

### Raster size

When working with larger rasters it is recommended to include the `-t widhthxheight` switch within raster2pgsql. You can alternatively use `-t auto` to have raster2pgsql compute an appropriate tile size.

As user dustymugs (a PostGIS developer) mentions in their [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32073/50240) to a previous question, the maximum dimensions allowed for a single raster are 65535 x 65535 and the size limit for a field in PostgreSQL is 1GB. Therefore, if your raster exceeds either limitation you will have to tile it.