# raster2pgsql: "Could not allocate memory for INSERT statement"

Tags: postgis, raster2pgsql

I'm very new to raster2pgsql so please bear with me.

I'm trying to load a 60mb .tif into my postgis-enabled database via raster2pgsql using the following command:

> raster2pgsql -s 5235 -C -F *.tif public.hrsl_lka | psql -h localhost
> -U postgres -p 5432

However, I get the following error message:

> ERROR: insert_records: Could not allocate memory for INSERT statement
> ERROR: process_rasters: Could not convert raster tiles into INSERT or
> COPY statements ERROR: Unable to process rasters

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.4, 64-bit. raster2pgsql has worked fine before for smaller raster files of around 3mb.

Does this have to do with the size of the image?

Comment: @gregorhur could you have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254328/psql-import-raster-out-of-memory and possibly try the -t option?

Comment: Hi Timothy, yes, that was indeed it! I must have double posted this question. Jim also pointed me to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238350/raster2pgsql-could-not-allocate-memory-for-insert-statement/65288824#65288824

Thanks!